# Finding facts of a template which has something in common with another template

Tags: clips

I am using CLIPS for a project.

I am using this template A which has an attribute model and another template B which has an attribute model as well.

So what I want to achieve is based on the attribute model, return those facts of template A which has the same attribute model value as of facts from template B.

I tried using this format

```
  (find-all-facts((?a template_A)(?b template_B))
    (and
      //condition to be met
    )
  )
```

it does give me the results, but it is giving me both the results for A and B which are duplicates.. How do I make it in a way it returns non duplicate values, either A or B?

Answer (score 1):

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate template_A
   (slot model))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate template_B
   (slot model))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts start
   (template_A (model 1))
   (template_A (model 2))
   (template_A (model 3))
   (template_B (model 2))
   (template_B (model 3))
   (template_B (model 4)))
CLIPS>    
(deffunction extract-every-nth-value (?values ?start ?increment)
   (bind ?rv (create$))
   (while (<= ?start (length$ ?values))
      (bind ?rv (create$ ?rv (nth$ ?start ?values)))
      (bind ?start (+ ?start ?increment)))
   (return ?rv))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (template_A (model 1))
f-2     (template_A (model 2))
f-3     (template_A (model 3))
f-4     (template_B (model 2))
f-5     (template_B (model 3))
f-6     (template_B (model 4))
For a total of 7 facts.
CLIPS> 
(find-all-facts ((?a template_A)(?b template_B))
    (eq ?a:model ?b:model))
(<Fact-2> <Fact-4> <Fact-3> <Fact-5>)
CLIPS>     
(extract-every-nth-value
   (find-all-facts ((?a template_A)(?b template_B))
    (eq ?a:model ?b:model))
   1 2)
(<Fact-2> <Fact-3>)
CLIPS>
```